# PHP splitting rows? (SEEMS IMPOSSIBLE TO DO)

Tags: php, mysql

my english is very bad and I am getting confused here, can someone help me?

My PHP:

```
<?php require("db.php"); ?>

<?php //Select All Orders
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$counter++;
    if($counter % 2 == 0) {
    echo "<div class='ui stackable six cards'>";
    echo $one[] = "<div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='".$row["avatar"]."'></div>";
    echo $two[] = "<div class='content'><a class='header'>Dias".$row["username"]."</a></div></div>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  }

}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

So what I want to do is for every 2 rows I want to split.

So it would look like so:

```
<div class="ui stackable six cards">

                    <div class="ui card small">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="assets/img/players/dias.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Dias</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ui card small">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="assets/img/players/dias.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Dias</a>
                        </div>

</div>
```

And what seperates them is the "`<div class="ui stackable six cards">`" as well as the "`</div>`"

**How exactly do I make it split every 2 rows using my PHP code? I cannot figure it out**

So for every 2 rows that it finds in the database it needs to echo "`<div class="ui stackable six cards">`" and "`</div>`" at the end.

**IS THIS IMPOSSIBLE? IT SEEMS SO**

Comment: I didn't explain that very well, nobody seemed to understand me

Comment: @dallider So edit that question, instead of posting a new one

Answer (score -1):

I'll suggest a toggling boolean technique instead of a modulo condition because I find it easier to read.  This method will also complete your outer (grouping) div generation if you have an odd number of rows in your resultset.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d38899a11f96d9a5ac2496e732f6be590a48e4f))

```
$resultset=[
    ['avatar'=>1,'username'=>'A'],
    ['avatar'=>2,'username'=>'B'],
    ['avatar'=>3,'username'=>'C'],
    ['avatar'=>4,'username'=>'D'],
    ['avatar'=>5,'username'=>'E'],
    ['avatar'=>6,'username'=>'F']
];
if(sizeof($resultset)){  // your num rows
    $new_group=true;
    foreach($resultset as $row){ // you while loop
        if($new_group){
            echo "<div class='ui stackable six cards'>";  // start new group
        }
        echo "<div class='ui card small'>";
            echo "<div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='".$row["avatar"]."'></div>";
            echo "<div class='content'><a class='header'>Dias".$row["username"]."</a></div></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        if(!$new_group){echo "</div>";}  // end group
        $new_group=!$new_group; // toggle the boolean value
    }
    if(!$new_group){  // if new group is not closed by the "second" member in the group
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<div class='ui stackable six cards'>
    <div class='ui card small'>
        <div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='1'></div>
        <div class='content'><a class='header'>DiasA</a></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class='ui card small'>
        <div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='2'></div>
        <div class='content'><a class='header'>DiasB</a></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='ui stackable six cards'>
    <div class='ui card small'>
        <div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='3'></div>
        <div class='content'><a class='header'>DiasC</a></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class='ui card small'>
        <div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='4'></div>
        <div class='content'><a class='header'>DiasD</a></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='ui stackable six cards'>
    <div class='ui card small'>
        <div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='5'></div>
        <div class='content'><a class='header'>DiasE</a></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class='ui card small'>
        <div class='ui card small'><div class='image'><img src='6'></div>
        <div class='content'><a class='header'>DiasF</a></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```